# How to unistall mailcow from terminal?

Tags: mail-server

I have recently installed mailcow from terminal using the following commands

```
$cd /opt
$sudo git clone https://github.com/mailcow/mailcow-dockerized
$cd mailcow-dockerized
```

I tried to uninstall using the following command;

```
docker-compose down -v --rmi all --remove-orphans
```

I get the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 125, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 47, in project_from_options
  File "compose/config/environment.py", line 77, in from_env_file
  File "compose/config/environment.py", line 72, in _initialize
  File "compose/config/environment.py", line 43, in env_vars_from_file
  File "/code/.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 904, in open
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './.env'
[46234] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete installation guide can be found [here](https://mailcow.github.io/mailcow-dockerized-docs/i_u_m_install/). (the installation instructions in the question is incomplete)

If you plan to uninstall `mailcow-dockerized` follow the [Deinstallation guide](https://mailcow.github.io/mailcow-dockerized-docs/i_u_m_deinstall/):

```
docker-compose down -v --rmi all --remove-orphans
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work please check error above

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm too late to the party, but I got this error when I ran this command as a normal user, not as a root user.

And if you still get an error message after logging in as a root user, (eg. HTTP request took too long to complete), check you're in `/opt/mailcow-dockerize`, then try:

```
docker-compose stop
```

and then run the uninstall command

```
docker-compose down -v --rmi all --remove-orphans
```